# SQL: Speed Improvement - Left Join on cond1 or cond2

Tags: sql, performance, join, left-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.*, b.*
FROM             current_tbl a
LEFT JOIN        import_tbl  b 
                 ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id 
                   OR ( a.f_name||' '||a.l_name = b.f_name||' '||b.l_name)
                 )
```

- Two tables that are basically the same
- I don't have access to the table structure or data input (thus no cleaning up primary keys)
- Sometimes the user_id is populated in one and not the other
- Sometimes names are equal, sometimes they are not

I've found that I can get the most of the data by matching on `user_id` or the first/last names.  I'm using the `' '` between the names to avoid cases where one user has the same first name as another's last name and both are missing the other field (unlikely, but plausible).

This query runs in 33000ms, whereas individualized they are each about 200ms.

- I've been up late and can't think straight right now
- I'm thinking that I could do a `UNION` and only query by name where a user_id does not exist (the default join is the user_id, if a user_id doesn't exist then I want to join by the name)
- Here is some free points to anyone that wants to help

Please don't ask for the execution plan.

Comment: Dude, in general, avoid comparing concatenating expressions like they were the plague. It is a no-no for a lot more reasons that can be discussed with a single comment. Rely on basic boolean expressions as much as possible (and whenever possible.) Specially if the individual fields are indexed. See Andomar's and Joe Stefanelli's answers to your question.

Comment: The concatenation was there for some reason, which I forget.  I agree boolean comparison would be better, but that is only one part of the problem.  It's the `OR` that I'm mainly concerned with.  Thinking sub-queries might be better performers.  Removing the concatenation dropped the query down to 21K ms

Comment: I think I remember why I was concatenating the names, I think there were names like `Jon van Son`, where 'van' was not a middle name.  I think there were discrepancies between sources where it might be included in the first name field ('jon van') and other times it might be part of the last name ('van son').  Concatenating the two fields was the only way I could think to easily compare the different sources, seeing how I can't edit the underlying data.  Also you can [index on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If people's suggestions don't provide a major speed increase, there is a possibility that your real problem is that the best query plan for your two possible join conditions is different.  For that situation you would want to do two queries and merge results in some way.  This is likely to make your query much, much uglier.

One obscure trick that I have used for that kind of situation is to do a GROUP BY off of a UNION ALL query.  The idea looks like this:

```
SELECT a_field1, a_field2, ...
  MAX(b_field1) as b_field1, MAX(b_field2) as b_field2, ...
FROM (
      SELECT a.field_1 as a_field1, ..., b.field1 as b_field1, ...
      FROM current_tbl a
        LEFT JOIN import_tbl b
          ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    UNION ALL
      SELECT a.field_1 as a_field1, ..., b.field1 as b_field1, ...
      FROM current_tbl a
        LEFT JOIN import_tbl b
          ON a.f_name = b.f_name AND a.l_name = b.l_name
  )
GROUP BY a_field1, a_field2, ...
```

And now the database can do each of the two joins using the most efficient plan.

(Warning of a drawback in this approach.  If a row in current_tbl joins to multiple rows in import_tbl, then you'll wind up merging data in a very odd way.)

Incidental random performance tip.  Unless you have reason to believe that there are potential duplicate rows, avoid DISTINCT.  It forces an implicit GROUP BY, which can be expensive.

Comment: This is similar to what I'm looking for; an uglier query to test out.  I'll give it a shot, thanks

Comment: Okay, this is what I had before, however it's the outer portion that I'm having trouble with.  Instead of using a `UNION ALL` and a `GROUP BY`, I've used a `UNION` instead.

Comment: Ahh, I think I'm onto the answer - thank you coffee.  I tried the `UNION` earlier, but The problem exists because it's a `LEFT JOIN`, it's providing the `user_id` twice if it matches in one case, but not the other.  I think the solution would be to test for a `null` in the parent query.

Comment: You should avoid UNION unless needed because it has an implicit GROUP BY.  Also note that in my code sample I am deliberately renaming the fields from the tables to avoid conflict.

Comment: Well `UNION` is getting rid of your `GROUP BY`.  Also a tip about the `DISTINCT`, it's not just an implicit GROUP BY, it's a GROUP BY and then a sort - the performance impact is from the sort, not the grouping.

Comment: While it wasn't the full solution, you forced me to wake up and actually think about my problem.  The solution I came up with is posed as another question.

Comment: @vol7ron: I am glad that it helped.  As for the cost of GROUP BY, in many implementations GROUP BY is implemented through a sort, so the cost of the sort is part of the cost of the GROUP BY.  But it can also be implemented as a hash, in which case the cost of the hash is part of the cost of the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you can easily avoid the string concatenation:

```
OR ( a.f_name||' '||a.l_name = b.f_name||' '||b.l_name)
```

Change it to:

```
OR ( a.f_name = b.f_name AND a.l_name = b.l_name)
```

Comment: That is correct - plus the underlying db engine might be able to take advantage of existing indexes on the individual fields if they exist. Wanton (and quite commonly unindexed/unindexable) concatenation is the bane of db performance.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what concatenation was being used - good point though.  I'm mainly concerned with the `OR`, though.  Hoping that using subqueries might increase performance.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than concatenating first and last name and comparing them, try comparing them individually instead. Assuming you have them (and you should create them if you don't), this should improve your chances of using indexes on the first name and last name columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.*, b.*
FROM             current_tbl a
LEFT JOIN        import_tbl  b 
                 ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id 
                   OR (a.f_name = b.f_name and a.l_name = b.l_name)
                 )
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know what concatenation was being used - good point though.  I'm mainly concerned with the `OR`, though.  Hoping that using subqueries might increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you're concatenating those strings.  Seems like that's where your slowdown would be.  Does this work instead?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  a.*, b.* 
FROM             current_tbl a 
LEFT JOIN        import_tbl  b  
                 ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id  
                   OR ( a.f_name = b.f_name AND a.l_name = b.l_name) 
                )
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know what concatenation was being used - good point though.  I'm mainly concerned with the `OR`, though.  Hoping that using subqueries might increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Yet Another Ugly Way To Do It.

```
SELECT a.*
  , CASE WHEN b.user_id IS NULL THEN c.field1 ELSE b.field1 END as b_field1
  , CASE WHEN b.user_id IS NULL THEN c.field2 ELSE b.field2 END as b_field2
  ...
FROM current_tbl a
  LEFT JOIN import_tbl b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
  LEFT JOIN import_tbl c
    ON a.f_name = c.f_name AND a.l_name = c.l_name;
```

This avoids any GROUP BY, and also handles conflicting matches in a somewhat reasonable way.

Comment: While I think the double joins are an alternative to the UNION, I think you may be missing the point with CASE statements.  I've updated the question; See my expected result table.  And refer to the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JOIN hints:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx

We were encountering the same type of behavior with one of our queries. As a last resort we added the LOOP hint, and the query ran much much faster.

It's important to note that Microsoft says this about JOIN hints:

> Because the SQL Server query optimizer typically selects the best execution plan for a query, we recommend that hints, including , be used only as a last resort by experienced developers and database administrators.

Comment: That could be helpful, however that is database-specific optimization.  I'm trying to do standard SQL optimization.  Most of my databases are Postgres/Oracle, so I try to keep to the iso standard.  In case you were confused, the `sql` tag doesn't refer to SQL Server, but to SQL in general.  I think sql-ng refers to SQL Server.  Thanks for the input though, I'm sure it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

my boss at my last job.. I swear.. he thought that using UNIONS was ALWAYS FASTER THAN OR.

For example.. instead of writing

Select * from employees Where Employee_id = 12 or employee_id = 47

he would write (and have me write)

Select * from employees Where employee_id = 12
UNION
Select * from employees Where employee_id = 47

SQL Sever optimizer said that this was the right thing to do in SOME situations.. I have a friend who works on the SQL Server team at Microsoft, I emailed him about this and he told me that my stats were out of date or something along those lines.

I never really got a good answer on WHY the unions are faster, it seems REALLY counter-intuitive.

I'm not recommending you DO this, but in some situations it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Also two more things-- GET RID OF THE DISTINCT CLAUSE unless you absolutely need it.. n

and more importantly, you can easily get rid of the concatenation in your join, like this for example (pardon my lack of mySQL knowledge)

SELECT DISTINCT  a.*, b.*
FROM             current_tbl a
LEFT JOIN        import_tbl  b 
                 ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id 
                   OR ( a.f_name = b.f_name and a.l_name = b.l_name)
                 )

I've had some tests at work in a similiar situation that show 10x performance improvement by getting rid of the simple concatenation in your join

Comment: In most scenarios you are correct, but in the question's comments it was explained why concatenation was used.  Still, the problem was in the `OR`