# SQL: Speed Improvement - Cluttered union query

Tags: sql, join, left-join, sql-optimization

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT       a.user_id, a.f_name, a.l_name, b.user_id, b.f_name, b.l_name
    FROM         current_tbl a
    INNER JOIN   import_tbl  b 
                 ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id )
    UNION
    SELECT       a.user_id, a.f_name, a.l_name, b.user_id, b.f_name, b.l_name
    FROM         current_tbl a
    INNER JOIN   import_tbl  b 
                 ON (   lower(a.f_name)=lower(b.f_name) 
                    AND lower(a.l_name)=lower(b.l_name) ) 
) foo
--
UNION
--
SELECT a.user_id , a.f_name , a.l_name , '' , '' , '' 
FROM   current_tbl a
WHERE  a.user_id NOT IN (
   select user_id from(
      SELECT       a.user_id, a.f_name, a.l_name, b.user_id, b.f_name, b.l_name
      FROM         current_tbl a
      INNER JOIN   import_tbl  b 
                   ON ( a.user_id = b.user_id )
      UNION
      SELECT       a.user_id, a.f_name, a.l_name, b.user_id, b.f_name, b.l_name
      FROM         current_tbl a
      INNER JOIN   import_tbl  b 
                   ON (   lower(a.f_name)=lower(b.f_name) 
                      AND lower(a.l_name)=lower(b.l_name) ) 
   ) bar
)
ORDER BY user_id
```

**Example of table population**:

current_tbl:

```
-------------------------------
user_id  |  f_name  |  l_name
---------+----------+----------
  A1     |  Adam    |  Acorn
  A2     |  Beth    |  Berry
  A3     |  Calv    |  Chard
         |          |
```

import_tbl:

```
-------------------------------
user_id  |  f_name  |  l_name
---------+----------+----------
  A1     |  Adam    |  Acorn
  A2     |  Beth    |  Butcher  <- last_name different
         |          |
```

Expected Output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
user_id1  |  f_name1  |  l_name1  |  user_id2  |  f_name2  |  l_name2
----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------
   A1     |  Adam     |  Acorn    |     A1     |  Adam     |  Acorn       
   A2     |  Beth     |  Berry    |     A2     |  Beth     |  Butcher
   A3     |  Calv     |  Chard    |            |           |
```

Doing this method gets rid of conditions where the row would be:

```
   A2     |  Beth     |  Berry    |     A2     |  Beth     |  Butcher
```

But it keeps the A3 row

---

I hope this makes sense and I haven't overly simplified it.  This is a continuation question from my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018627/sql-speed-improvement-left-join-on-cond1-or-cond2).  The succession of these improvements has dropped the query down from ~32000ms to where it's at now ~1200ms - quite an improvement.

I supect I can optimize by using `UNION ALL` in the subquery and of course the usual index optimizations, but I'm looking for the best SQL optimization.  FYI this particular case is for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is the database really using a case-sensitive collation which requires the use of the Lower function?

Comment: You realize that when you join on "lower(field) = lower(field)" you've destroyed the ability of the optimizer to use indexes on the fields, right?

Comment: Yeah, can't really optimize this properly, even with indexes...

Comment: I think PostgreSQL allows you to [index on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/indexes-expressional.html).. or [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/9-How-to-create-an-index-based-on-a-function.html)

Comment: @Thomas: I think so because of international names and names like 'McDonald'.  @le dorfier and @LorenVS : my last comment applies to you guys if you want to respond

Comment: @vol7ron - The only change I made to your post was the postgresql tag which you should re-add. The database product (and version) makes all the difference in the world in available solutions. If it is not postgresql, then by all means add the appropriate tag for the correct database.

Comment: @Thomas: this is more of a fundamental/theoretical SQL question, though. I know different databases have different planners and thus unique execution paths, which yield different performance; but I think this would apply the same way to Postgres as it would to Oracle, DB2, and SQL Server. I try to keep the majority of my code to SQL specs, that's why I took the pg out - this is in case we want to use a different DBMS in the future. When tuning, I have enough knowledge to take what others have to say and apply the best Pg-specific optimizations.

Comment: I've used database-specific tags in other questions when they've applied, but I don't see it applying to one specific database in this circumstance.  I also don't want people that have `postgresql` as an ignored tag to exclude this question, since it doesn't directly apply to Pg.  The only thing that seems to be Pg-specific is the function-indexing, which doesn't really affect the example. I won't deny that it does show that some users (Loren/le dorfier) aren't as aware, but they still brought good points in case outside viewers happened upon this question.

Comment: @vol7ron - It is a non-sequitur to ask for the best performing solution in the theoretical sense. Different products perform differently with various query elements. They support different features which can dramatically affect the solution. For example, the use of the `lower` function in your OP is a quirk of using Postgres that would not be needed with SQL Server depending on the collation. Indexes would be off the table since that is an implementation-specific feature. Thus, your question is unanswerable as there is no means to verify "best performing".

Comment: @Thomas: I thought I addressed that when I said, `I know different databases have different planners and thus unique execution paths, which yield different performance; but I think this would apply the same way to Postgres as it would to Oracle, DB2, and SQL Server. I try to keep the majority of my code to SQL specs`.  There are aspects of SQL optimization that apply to every database, such as filtering on a WHERE before joining, versus doing it afterwards.

Comment: @vol7ron - Again, there is no way to verify "speed improvement" without testing it on a specific database product. For example, SQL Server handles Exists expressions better than MySQL and probably Postgres. It might be that one database smartly breaks up a Union All query into parallel executions whereas the others do not. Even your example of using a Where clause isn't necessarily true if the table is small (meaning there would be no difference). Using the `lower` function as you have in your OP would perform horribly on SQL Server because it cannot create indexes on expressions and so on.

Comment: @vol7ron - RE: indexes expressions I'm excluding workarounds such as computed columns or indexed views which again are implementation specific performance tools.

Comment: @Thomas: While you are right, we could easily go back and forth about this :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is almost identical, much smaller and seems
to make more sense to me. My first instinct is that it
should run a bunch faster, might not be the best though :)

```
SELECT       a.user_id, a.f_name, a.l_name, 
             COALESCE(b.user_id, ''), COALESCE(b.f_name, ''), COALESCE(b.l_name, '')
FROM         current_tbl a
LEFT OUTER JOIN import_tbl  b ON
   ( a.user_id = b.user_id ) OR
   ( lower(a.f_name)=lower(b.f_name) 
     AND lower(a.l_name)=lower(b.l_name) )
```

EDIT:
Laugh at myself for more or less recommending you reverse the previous changes
you made in your original question.

Comment: Yeah, the `OR` was a bottleneck, perhaps I can optimize it more... I'm still running the past 48 hours on 2 hours sleep.

Comment: although I couldn't use the above, +1 for the attempt